# How to refresh images added via addSubview?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, view

I have views - cards, like in Tinder, and I want to add images via `addSubview` to these cards. I did it and all work, but here I have some problem:

For example, I have 3 cards and an array `images`. When I swipe my cards, I increment my `cardIndex++`. So, when I swipe my cards I print cardIndex and it shows me in logs correctly. Image names prints correctly, also, but images don't change on my cards.

[image: Look, here:]

How can I update my cards views before I show a new image?

I've tried to set imageView to nil after showing image, but it doesn't work, too:

```
_ = UIImageView(image: nil)
```

Here is my function:

```
        var images = ["apple.jpg", "orange.jpg", "banana.jpg"]
        swipeableView.nextView = {
            let cardView = CardView(frame: self.swipeableView.bounds)
            cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

            if self.loadCardsFromXib {
                let contentView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CardContentView", owner: self, options: nil).first! as! UIView

                contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                contentView.backgroundColor = cardView.backgroundColor

                let cardHeight = self.swipeableView.frame.height
                let cardWidth = self.swipeableView.frame.width

                // Mark: Adding Image to cards
                let image = UIImage(named: self.images[self.cardIndex])
                let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
                imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cardWidth, height: cardHeight - 70)
                contentView.addSubview(imageView)

                cardView.addSubview(contentView)

                _ = UIImageView(image: nil)
            }

            return cardView
       }
```

**UPDATE**

```
    swipeableView.didStart = {view, location in
        if self.cardIndex+1 < self.swipeableView.numPrefetchedViews {
            self.cardIndex++
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `_ = UIImageView(image: nil)` supposed to mean? It does not set `imageView` to nil.

Comment: @mixel can you offer something to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check and increment `cardIndex` in `swipeableView.nextView` closure:

```
var images = ["apple.jpg", "orange.jpg", "banana.jpg"]
self.cardIndex = 0
swipeableView.nextView = {

    if self.cardIndex >= images.count {
        return nil
    }

    let cardView = CardView(frame: self.swipeableView.bounds)
    cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    if self.loadCardsFromXib {
        let contentView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CardContentView", owner: self, options: nil).first! as! UIView

        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.backgroundColor = cardView.backgroundColor

        let cardHeight = self.swipeableView.frame.height
        let cardWidth = self.swipeableView.frame.width

        // Mark: Adding Image to cards
        let image = UIImage(named: self.images[self.cardIndex])
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cardWidth, height: cardHeight - 70)
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)

        cardView.addSubview(contentView)
    }
    self.cardIndex++
    return cardView
}
```

To get current showing card index you should define other `currentCardIndex`:

```
let currentCardIndex = 0
```

and set `swipeableView.didSwipe`:

```
swipeableView.didSwipe = {
    _, _, _ in
    self.currentCardIndex++
}
```

Comment: I increment it, how I described in my question. I just did not add to my question this code. Look at my question again, please. I've updated it. So, it increments and shows correct image titles, but doesn't change an image

Comment: Are you sure that `swipeableView.didStart` is executed before `swipeableView.nextView`? And it seems that `self.cardIndex+1 < self.swipeableView.numPrefetchedViews` is false after showing first card when `self.swipeableView.numPrefetchedViews` is 1.

Comment: if you want, I can send you a project. Paste it on Github, you can look at it

Comment: it's here: https://github.com/orkhanalizade/StackO there must be change apple - orange - apple - orange, but instead of this, it changes apple - orange and stays on orange

Comment: As I said you are not correctly check and increment `cardIndex`. You should do it in `swipeableView.nextView` not in `swipeableView.didStart`.

Comment: But I cannot oncrement it in nextView, because in nextView it increments not to +1, but +5. Thats why. You can try it and will see how it increments there :/

Comment: It increments step by step to 5 because you set `swipeableView.numPrefetchedViews = 4` so it instantiates four first card views immediately when view controller loads.

Comment: I launched your application with code fixes from my answer and it works correctly.

Comment: it works! Thanks! It's strange! Before the SO, I did exactly the same, but it didn't work, but now it works.  Thank you again!

Comment: If you need to know current showing card index then you should define other `currentCardInde`, set `swipeableView.didSwipe` and increment `currentCardIndex` there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep reference to your `UIImageView` (by making a class level/global variable) and set the new image on swipe. Something like this:

```
var imageView : UIImageView // Declare in global context - outside all class functions
```

Then access it from inside functions (both first time & with any change in image index):

```
imageView = UIImageView(image: image!) // Do not re-define like let imageView
```

Comment: Can you please show how you are doing this. This must work. In your current code you have a local reference of `UIImageView` which is why you wouldn't be able to change the image.  Can you show code where you are setting it initially and then resetting it back.

Comment: I do it like you said:

`class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var imageView : UIImageView!`

and later how I've described above, without `let`, just `imageView`

Comment: That should have worked. Alternatively, can you please try adding a `imageView` variable in your `CardView` class. Add a image view inside your custom view  `CardView` class. Set it like `cardView.imageView.image = <Your_First_Image>`. Keep a global reference to `cardView` object and then when new image is selected simply call `cardView.imageView.image = <Your_Second_Image>`

Comment: Can you share github link of your project? @OrkhanAlizade

Comment: it's here: https://github.com/orkhanalizade/StackO there must be change apple - orange - apple - orange, but instead of this, it changes apple - orange and stays on orange